# How to create a multiple null-terminated char array?

Tags: c

I have a char array and I want it to have a certain format, for example:

> (first 4 bytes) block type
>   (next 4 bytes) error code
>   (next 32 bytes)
>   email address
>   (next 64 bytes) home address
>   (next 32 bytes) Full Name

and so forth. About 45 different fields that are padded with 0's to field size. I can use `memcpy` and advance the pointer each time by the field size but it seems like a tedious task and an ugly code. Maybe a more clever and elegant way to create such a format?

Comment: Why don't you use a `struct`?

Comment: I need the padding 0's, not just a struct of strings

Comment: Your original approach is fine. If there are lot of these things, you might want to create a DSL and generate C code from that.

Comment: @susdu about the zero padding: Unlike popular belief, `strncpy` is for this exactly. It will pad with zeros.

Comment: Use a struct and memset the struct to 0 then fill it?

Comment: @bolov, this is an interesting feature. However, this char array isn't a string so the string functions wouldn't play nice with it.

Comment: @bolov: It is worth noting that `strncpy` will pad with zeroes, but it will _not_ put an ending zero is there is no room for it. Exactly how these structures used to be used a few decades ago...

Comment: @susdu: There's no such thing as a "string" in C, there are only `char` arrays. It sounds like a sruct and `strncpy` is exactly what you need here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do such it using `union` together with `struct`:

```
#define BLOCK_TYPE_SIZE    4
#define ERROR_CODE_SIZE    4
#define EMAIL_ADDRESS_SIZE 32
#define HOME_ADDRESS_SIZE  64
#define FULL_NAME_SIZE     32

struct format_entry
{
    char block_type[BLOCK_TYPE_SIZE];
    char error_code[ERROR_CODE_SIZE];
    char email_address[EMAIL_ADDRESS_SIZE];
    char home_address[HOME_ADDRESS_SIZE];
    char full_name[FULL_NAME_SIZE];
};

union format_union
{
    char full_string[sizeof(struct format_entry)];
    struct format_entry entry;
};
```

And then you can fill it in like these:

```
union format_union f;
memset (f.full_string, 0, sizeof f.full_string);
strcpy (f.entry.block_type, "TYPE");
strcpy (f.entry.error_code, "CODE");
strcpy (f.entry.email_address, "EM@AI.L");
strcpy (f.entry.home_address, "ADDR");
strcpy (f.entry.full_name, "NA ME");
```

Comment: You can access whole structure as `char[]` rather than doing `(char*) &f`

Comment: But the only thing you use `full_string` for is to `memset()` the whole structure, and you don't need a cast for that - you can just do `memset(&f, 0, sizeof f)`.

Comment: And of course, you don't need `memset()` at all. Just initialize the whole thing to all zeros with `f = {{0}}`.

Answer (score 1):

[`strncpy()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strncpy.html), despite its name, is **not** a "string" function

```
char data[136/* maybe add 1 for extra '\0' */] = {0}; // fill array with zeroes
strncpy(data, "block type", 4);
strncpy(data + 4, "error code", 4);
strncpy(data + 8, "email address", 32);
strncpy(data + 40, "home address ...", 64);
strncpy(data + 104, "Full Name even if it is very very long", 32);
```

Comment: The original approach to offset handling was so much better ("advance the pointer each time by the field size"). With your approach adding a new field in the middle or code-reviewing is a PITA.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Nick's response, in C, *but not C++,* you can skip the union and directly zero the structure:

```
struct format_entry
{
    char block_type[BLOCK_TYPE_SIZE];
    char error_code[ERROR_CODE_SIZE];
    char email_address[EMAIL_ADDRESS_SIZE];
    char home_address[HOME_ADDRESS_SIZE];
    char full_name[FULL_NAME_SIZE];
};
struct format_entry data;

memset( &data, 0, sizeof data );   /* zero-fill structure */
```

If you need to update just some of the fields later on you might also consider making your own fill routine that assures zero fill.

```
char *strncpy0( char *target, const char *source, size_t s )
{
    memset( target, 0, s );
    strncpy( target, source, s );
    return target;
}
```

While the above code is safer for early users of C, to be more efficient you could calculate the number of bytes at the end of target that strncpy() will not touch, then just fill those bytes.

Answer (score 0):

That's truly a tedious task. But it seems there is no better way.

Maybe you could conceal them into functions and never consider the ugly code inside.